# UDP Broadcast on Android Emulator

Tags: c#, networking, xamarin, android-emulator

I am developing an Android app using Xamarin. This app sends a UDP broadcast on a specific port, that is received by a device on the same network, and the device then replies some data back to the app. There can be multiple devices, so the app keeps reading UDP responses until a timeout.

The device for now is a simple c# windows forms application running on the host, and the app is running on the android emulator.

The problem is that the host (nor the device application) receive any packet on the port.

this is the code that sends the broadcast on the android app:

```
public async Task SendBroadcast()
{
    UdpClient c = new UdpClient();
    c.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    c.EnableBroadcast = true;
    string msg = "...device_key...";
    await c.SendAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg), msg.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 55566));
}
```

If I change the `IPAddress.Broadcast` to use the host address `10.0.2.2` it works as expected.

Any ideas how I can get the broadcast packet to reach the local network?

Comment: Are you using `IPAddress.Any` on your receiving client?

Comment: yes, the receiving client uses `IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 55566)`.

Comment: This is a misuse of broadcast. Broadcast should only be used if you need to interrupt _every_ host on a LAN because that is what it does. If you know the IP address, then use unicast, otherwise you can use multicast. One of the improvement that IPv6 has over IPv4 is the elimination of broadcast. Many companies will not even consider applications that misuse broadcast because it clogs the network and interrupts every host, even when the hosts have no interest in the broadcast packets.

Comment: I have the same problem! I think it's due to the emulator's special network, it does some magic work like forwarding, in the host server, the received packet shows its address is 127.0.0.1 instead of 10.0.2.15, they are two different subnet, which is not reachable by broadcast

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using the "10.0.2.2" address is the right path, at least, on the Android emulator. The usage of the "IPAddress.Broadcast" constant will work ONLY on a physical device. On an emulator there's no way to send a standard broadcast message. The reason of this is because Android emulators have a special network configuration to work. A a private network is created and maybe that network is not redirecting the broadcast message to the host network.